# Looking to convert a statement from using a single parameter to using a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am refactoring a stored procedure and I have the following issue:

I have this statement:

```
SELECT Top 1 unit_gid
FROM Some_Table  
WHERE  group_gid = @i_group_gid
ORDER BY effective_date desc
```

Now instead of supplying one group gid as a single parameter like in the above I wish to apply this statement to a collection of group gids which I have stored as a single column table.

So if I supply a list of 20 group gids I want to return a list 20 unit gids, the most recent one for each of those supplied group gids.

How can I do this without resorting to using loops? Is there a way that I can do it with CTEs for example?

Comment: Did you try a join?

Comment: @Paparazzi I considered it but I don't know how I'd be able to use that along with the TOP to get the exact 20 results that I'm interested in. Using a TOP 20 and the same orderby might return multiples of some groups and none of others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could join on the tables of `gids`, and use the `row_number` window function to get the most recent `unit_gid` per `gid`:

```
SELECT gid, unit_gid
FROM   (SELECT s.gid AS gid,
               unit_gid,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY gid ORDER BY effective_date DESC) rn
        FROM   some_table s
        JOIN   gids g ON s.gid = gids.gid) t
WHERE  rn = 1
```

Comment: Ok thank you that looks promising. I'll come back and give you the tick when I get it implemented with my code